# How to write to std::ostream without formatting?

Tags: c++, c++11, io, formatting

For example, I want to write `std::string my_str( "foobar\n" );` literally into `std::ostream&` with the backslash-n intact (**no formatting**).

Perhaps I need to convert `my_str` with a formatting function that converts backslash to double-backslash first?  Is there a standard library function for that?

Or maybe there is a directive I can pass to `std::ostream&`?

Comment: `\n` gets replaced by the compiler. It's already gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this for larger strings is with raw string literals:

```
std::string my_str(R"(foobar\n)");
```

If you want parentheses in it, use a delimiter:

```
R"delim(foobar\n)delim"
```

I don't know of anything that will let you keep the escape codes etc. in the string, but output it without, but `std::transform` with an `std::ostream_iterator<std::string>` destination and a function that handles the cases you want should do it, as it does in [this example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2ZFKjF%241):

```
std::string filter(char c) {
   if (c == '\n') return "\\n";
   if (c == '\t') return "\\t";
   //etc
   return {1, c};
}

int main() {
   std::string str{"abc\nr\tt"};
   std::cout << "Without transform: " << str << '\n';

   std::cout << "With transform: ";
   std::transform(std::begin(str), std::end(str), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout), filter);
}
```

Comment: If `str` is declared `"Hello\xAWorld"`, it will be transformed to `"Hello\\nWorld"`

Comment: @balki, I get `Hello\nWorld` in LWS, but yeah, it won't work for hex escapes, you're right, or octal ones for that matter. That's just the way escape codes work, replaced with actual characters. Whereas `\t` produces an easy character to check for, `\x` could be anything, so it would take quite a bit more effort. That is a valid concern, though.

Answer (score 4):

Since `"foobar\n"` is a constant literal, just write it as `"foobar\\n"`, so that `"\\"` becomes `"\"`, letting `n` to leave in peace.

What you call "formatting" is not.

The stream does not *format* the string. The substitution of `"\n"` with `char(10)` is made by the compiler when producing the actual value form the literal. (ostream will at most translate `char(10)` into `{ char(10), char(13) }` if the underlying platform requires it, but that's another story).

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to `std::ostream` or `std::string`. `"foobar\n"` is a literal where `\n` already means end of line.

You have two options:

1. Escape `\n` symbol by `\` 
    `std::string str("foobar\\n");`
2. Use modern C++11 raw string literal
    `std::string str(R"(foobar\n)");`

Answer (score 2):

The "backslash + n" is not formatted by the stream; for example the length of `std::string("\n")` is **1** (and not 2). Likewise `'\n'` is a single *character*. The fact that you write backslash + n is just a shortcut to represent non-printable (and non-ASCII) characters.

As another example, `'\x0a' == '\n'` (because `0a` is the hexadecimal code for the line-feed character). And `std::string("\x0a").size() == 1` too.

If (on Linux<sup>1</sup>) you open a `std::ofstream` and write `'\x0a'` to that stream, you will thus end up with a file containing a *single* byte; whose hexadecimal value is `0a`.

As such, it is not your stream that is transforming what you wrote, it is the compiler. Depending on your usecase, you may either want to:

- change the string as written in the code: using `"foobar\\n"` (note this increase the length by 1)
- perform a transformation while streaming to print the hexadecimal or escape code of non-printable characters

<sup>1</sup> on Windows, the `'\n'` character is translated to `"\r\n"` (carriage-return + line-feed) in text mode.